# Remote Windows and Windows Mobile

Tags: c#, windows-mobile

I need to find a way to remote & communicate between windows pc and windows mobile via C#. 
What is the best way to do it via C# ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We need a lot more info on exactly what you need to do.  For example [RAPI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa920177.aspx) provides a [communication interface](http://rapi.codeplex.com/) and you can write custom RAPI libraries.  That gives the PC the ability to [call methods on the device](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa917422.aspx), but it's a far, far cry from actual Remoting.

Comment: I want to do file transfer and if possible remoting like TeamViewer between PC and windows phone

Comment: Then RAPI certainly will fill the bill.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [dotnetremoting.com](http://dotnetremoting.com) which you can do that, ok it's commercial and may do what you are looking for.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, I'll look for open source library first

Comment: @Anton Setiawan: No problem :) But I doubt if there is such an open source implementation of this as remoting is not in use as much. I did try build an implementation using GenuineChannels (It was 99USD and came with source but the company went under - I think...it was on thin ground about two years ago) and tried to port it across but failed! I could suggest another way, employ sockets on the desktop and .NET CF, that would be the basic long winded way of 'remoting'. By serializing the data, and breaking it up into chunks as messages..you get the drift.. :) Good luck in your quest.

Answer (score 0):

have a look on this:
[Windows Mobile (C#) - Communicating between phone and PC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/344335/windows-mobile-c-communicating-between-phone-and-pc)

I would recommend using WCF, since it is a recent technology and would enable talking to any compatible device, not only to a windows pc.

br, Marcel